# Apache Camel multicast, exception and Aggregation strategy

Tags: exception, cxf, aggregate, apache-camel

I define a complex route in which I had to to orchestrate different simple operations.

```
   from(cxfCartEndpoint).routeId("receiveCart")
    .to("log:com.sdmo.input?level="+LOG_LEVEL)
    .process(cartWSExtractProcessor)
    .to(loggingMesssagesPath+"?fileName=originalRequest${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.xml")
    .multicast(aggregationStrategy).stopOnException()
       .to("mock:doNothing","direct:copyItem","direct:XmlSave","direct:manageFinalResponse")
        .end()
     .to(loggingMesssagesPath+"?fileName=finalResponse${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.xml")
     .process(new ConvertCartResponseProcessor())
     .to("log:com.sdmo.output?level="+LOG_LEVEL)
     ;
```

The from endpoint is a cxf WS in POJO mode, and I need to keep his header to be able to proceed the response, so the purpose of my aggregation strategy is to keep the original header.
I set the .stopOnException() option because I do not want to run step 2 if step 1 is not ok.
I throw exception with the following way in subroutes :

```
.choice()
  .when(not(successResponsePredicate))
    .to("log:com.sdmo.Error?level="+LOG_LEVEL)
    .throwException(new Exception("copyItemError"))
  .otherwise()
    .to("mock:CopyItemSuccess")
 .end();
```

Now I want to handle the exception in the aggregation strategy and compute a suitable error message to my web-service response.

If I define an exception behavior with the onException the exchange does not return to the aggregation strategy, I think I had to remove the stopOnException option, but I don't know how configure my aggregation strategy to skip the following multicast step

Comment: The AggregationStrategy should have the caused exception when the aggregate method is invoked.  
So is getException() null on the newExchange parameter?

Comment: When the exception is raised, the message does not reach the aggregation strategy.

Comment: Is this an effect of the onExceptionStop option?
If I disable this option is there a way to skip the remaining step of the multicast when detecting an exception in the aggregation strategy?

I tried the several kind of exception handling, whithout success, by the way, the doCatch(...) is not available in the java DSL ...

I am working with Camel 2.6, tomcat 6 on JDK 1.5

Comment: I think I missunderestand the issue when writting this question, I created another related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446444/apache-camel-cxf-empty-response-when-handling-exception