# Apache Camel CXF empty response when handling exception

Tags: exception, cxf, apache-camel

This question is related to the previous one : [Apache Camel multicast, exception and Aggregation strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317776/apache-camel-multicast-exception-and-aggregation-strategy)

I think I missunderstood the problem when asking the previous question.

I try to handle exception I thrown in my route.

```
.filter(not(successResponsePredicate))
    .to("log:com.sdmo.Error?level="+LOG_LEVEL)
    .transform(simple("Erreur lors de l'appel copyItem"))
    .process(new ConvertCartResponseProcessor())
    .throwException(new Exception("copyItemError"))
.end()
```

The exception is handled through this code :

```
onException(java.lang.Exception.class).handled(true).inOut("direct:thrownError");
from("direct:thrownError")
    .to("log:com.sdmo.output?level="+LOG_LEVEL);
```

My route is started by a cxf endpoint, but when the exception handling route achieved, the body returned to my WS client is empty.

I made several check with the debug mode and the log to ensure that the exception handling code set a response, and if I replace the body (POJO type) by a simple type, I got an unmarshall error when sending the reply.

The last line logged before the reply show the body is well defined :

```
INFO: Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOut, BodyType:com.access_commerce.cameleonws.cart.AddXMLResponse, Body:com.access_commerce.cameleonws.cart.AddXMLResponse@59dc73f9]
```

I guess that there is something wrong with my use of the InOut pattern or something like...

Comment: try calling setBody(constant("ERROR")) or transform(constant("ERROR")) in the onException clause instead of .inOut(...).  does that work at least?

Comment: The CXF endpoint is in POJO mode, if I had this transform, I got a marshalling error : ATTENTION: Interceptor for {http://www.access-commerce.com/cameleonWS/cart/}CartService#{http://www.access-commerce.com/cameleonWS/cart/}addXML has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream nor any of its super class is known to this context.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the handled() method call. It's preventing the exception from percolating up to the CXF endpoint.

Comment: I don't want to propagate  the exception to the cxf endpoint, I want to encapsulate it and return the error in the wsdl's response format

Comment: If that's what you really want to do( wrap Exception("copyItemError") ) add a processor on the end of your exception route that does the wrapping into what I presume is a JAXB annotated object. Camel then assumes you want to return that object, and the originating endpoint will translate it to XML for return. The process(new ConvertCartResponseProcessor()).throwException() looks like an anti-pattern. If the response processor gives you the bean that you want to return, remove the throwException().

Comment: I already tried to place the process(new ConvertCartResponseProcessor()) on the exception route and the behavior is the same : empty response. The use of a throw is to interrupt the current multicast

Comment: Multicast means that each path is run by a different thread, so no response will be returned. If you want to report errors from a multicast, you must aggregate the results and makes sense of them. See http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html for an example of how to do this.

Comment: As I explained in the other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317776/apache-camel-multicast-exception-and-aggregation-strategy If I set the stopOnException Option, the aggregation strategy is not called when exception is raised, and I had not find any solution to skip the remaining step when handling the exception in this strategy. I am currently trying to filter in each step of the multicast the exception state, but this is not a clean solution

Comment: Having read both of your questions again (could you please put all code in the one question next time), multicast isn't the pattern you are after. What you described is sequential invocation from("cxf:..").to("direct:first").to("direct:second")... if an exception is thrown, it will interrupt the route and return the error. If you want to handle an error in a special way use http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html in the main route.